# How to Create a Module Scoped Service without Circular Dependencies?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-module

EDIT: This has now been fixed thanks to the accepted answer, the stackblitz now contains working code

First of all I know its not recommended to create module scoped services, I just want to know if it is possible to do.

I have created a module, service and component. The code is below.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Fm5Component } from './fm5/fm5.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Fm5Component
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class FeatureModule5Module { }
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Fm5Service } from '../fm5.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fm5',
  templateUrl: './fm5.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fm5.component.scss']
})
export class Fm5Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(private fm5Service: Fm5Service) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fm5Service.saySomething();
  }

}
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FeatureModule5Module } from './feature-module5.module';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: FeatureModule5Module
})
export class Fm5Service {

  constructor() { }

  saySomething(){
    console.log("something");
  }
}
```

However when I try to run this I get a circular dependency error. Is it possible to fix this somehow?

I see that this question comes up quite a bit on here in various forms but I'm still none the wiser as to if it can be done.

I've created a stackblitz replicating the error:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tyavuk?file=src/app/feature-module5/fm5/fm5.service.ts

The error on stackblitz is
[image]

Comment: Can you post the exact error?

Comment: I see no circular dependency. If possible, create the scenario in this stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ngpkqb?file=src/module1/hello.component.ts

Comment: @PankajSati I've added that in to my post now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a known issue with Angular/Typescript. Check out this thread: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10170#issuecomment-415758304

> Generally, you should use `providedIn` property to limit it to a non-root module, when you are creating
> a thrid-party library. Because this feature was introduced for
> allowing tree shakeable services.

- In an application, you will write a service only if you intend to consume it. But in a library, a consumer may or may not consume it. Therefore, it requires tree-shaking.

**This is the Circular Dependency that is currently created:**

`service--[provides itself to]-->module--[declares]-->component--[depends on]-->service`.
This prevents the bundler from tree-shaking it. Therefore Angular warns you about using this pattern with a Circular Dependency error.

Understanding providers scope & `providedIn`: `XYZModule`.

- When you specify scope of a service(`XYZService`) with `providedIn` to a particular module, you are telling Angular -> **Hey Angular, please limit this service instance to the specified module.**
- Case 1: The `XYZModule` is imported by another module(s). In this case, the single instance of `XYZService` will be shared in that module. So, any component in that module can inject `XYZService` without any circular dependency error.
- Case 2: The `XYZModule` is imported by `AppModule`, In this case, your service instance will be shared throughout the application. Even with any lazy loaded module.
- Case 3: The `XYZModule` is imported by `AppModule` & `Module2` individually. In this case, `Module2` will create its own instance of `XYZService`. All components declared inside `Module2` will not share `AppModule`'s instance of `XYZService`

I have created the scenario in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-na4atc?file=src/app/lazy-feature3/lazy3.component.ts)

Use the `providers` array in the `@NgModule` to limit the scope of a service to that module when creating an application.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Fm5Component
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers:[Fm5Service]
})
export class FeatureModule5Module { }
```

Still, if you want to use `providedIn` syntax, check this visual to understand the problem & its solution using a new Module: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10170#issuecomment-414270051